# Magento - Order details not displayed in paypal standard

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2. I have configured the paypal standard for my site.While placing order from my site the user ordered details are displaying in one line with price in Paypal instead of displaying the product and shipping details.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting you want is called **Transfer Cart Line Items**. Setting this to yes under System > Configuration > Payment Methods > Paypal Standard (Hit Configure and Advanced Settings to show the setting) will under normal circumstances transfer the whole cart information to Paypal.

Comment: If I set yes for the "Transfer Cart Line Items" I cant see the order details on paypal and the shipping amount is added twice in paypal.

Comment: Is this with a default install? Do you have any other extensions installed which change the paypal behaviour?

Comment: At first we haven't redirected to paypal so We have plaed a centinel folder for redirection to paypal.we haven't used any extension.